# MS-Word text formatting gone wrong after pasting from another word document

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, fonts, copy-paste

I'm pasting text from one document into a new one. After pasting the text spacing seems to be different than the usual. If I paste it from same pdf file then font and spacing are alright. Below are the screenshots.

[Here's the correct font](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bFRRr.png)

[Here's how the text shouldn't look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkdmN.png)

The problem from pasting from pdf is that it is covering only half side if the page, so I thought it would be better if I pasted from Word document.

[Here's the word document from which I'm copying](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gykS1.png)

Comment: How about directly opening PDF in Word 2016? In Word, click File > Open, select the pdf file to open. Check if the text font changes or not.

Comment: In the pdf, there are 2 vertical columns of paras, so when I copy from it the text is getting pasted only in a vertical half and it is taking lot of work to indent it. @WinniL

Comment: When you paste, use that Paste Options icon beside the new test to select Paste Text Only. Or use right-click > Paste Options > Text Only. Then apply the proper paragraph style to the new text. That will set the correct fonts and spacing.